# When rendering components just for AT in Android, the focus indicator is visible once Talkback reaches them?

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm kind of stuck on android accessibility. I know from the brilliant video of Chris McMeeking (https://accessibility.deque.com/mobile-office-hours-accessible-carousels) that some components like Next and Prev buttons in a carousel can be rendered just by AT. More than once I have noticed in A11y mobile audits that some elements are like "off-screen" and there is no visible focus indicator, despite that, they are announced and they receive a11y focus, and is possible to interact with them. This is the point for my question, are these kinds of components the ones that are generated just by AT?